# interpolation for limited number of NA

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, interpolation, imputets

i have a dataframe df with a column containing values (meter reading). Some values are sporadically missing (NA).

df excerpt:

```
row   time      meter_reading
1     03:10:00  26400
2     03:15:00  NA
3     03:20:00  27200
4     03:25:00  28000
5     03:30:00  NA
6     03:35:00  NA
7     03:40:00  30000
```

What I'm trying to do:

If there is only one consecutive NA, I want to interpolate (e.g. na.interpolation for row 2).
But if there's two or more consecutive NA, I don't want R to interpolate and leave the values as NA. (e.g. row 5 and 6).

What I tried so far is loop (for...) with an if-condition. My approach:

```
library("imputeTS")
for(i in 1:(nrow(df))) {
  if(!is.na(df$meter_reading[i]) & is.na(df$meter_reading[i-1]) & !is.na(df$meter_reading[i-2])) {
    na_interpolation(df$meter_reading) 
    }
}
```

Giving me :

```
Error in if (!is.na(df$meter_reading[i]) & is.na(df$meter_reading[i -  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Any ideas how to do it? Am I completely wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, `ifelse` is vectorized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't knaow what is your na.interpolation, but taking the mean of previous and next rows for example, you could do that with dplyr :

```
df %>% mutate(x=ifelse(is.na(meter_reading),
                       (lag(meter_reading)+lead(meter_reading))/2,
                       meter_reading))
#  row     time meter_reading     x
#1   1 03:10:00         26400 26400
#2   2 03:15:00            NA 26800
#3   3 03:20:00         27200 27200
#4   4 03:25:00         28000 28000
#5   5 03:30:00            NA    NA
#6   6 03:35:00            NA    NA
#7   7 03:40:00         30000 30000
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick look shows that your counter `i` starts at 1 and then you try to get index at `i-1` and`i-2`.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition here, in the current **imputeTS** package version, there is also a `maxgap` option for each imputation algorithm, which easily solves this problem. Probably wasn't there yet, as you asked this question.

Your code would look like this:

```
library("imputeTS")
na_interpolation(df, maxgap = 1)
```

This means gaps of 1 NA get imputed, while longer gaps of consecutive NAs remain NA.